# Add second website to wordpress

Tags: wordpress

So I'm new to wordpress, and I'm managing a company's wordpress site while building another website for this company. They have paid for many plugins and themes in their wordpress account and I would like to use them for the new website. So my question is that what do I do in order to add this website from my local host to their wordpress account.

Should I just download their wordpress file into my laptop and create a new folder in that file? If so, then what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first: If you're are building another website using platform other than wordpress, then you cannot use plugins and themes.

But if you're, just download the wordpress plugins and themes from old site. And then, place those to your respective themes and plugins folder. If you are working on existing site, then you may need the existing sql file to test in the identical environments along with the data. There are many plugins which can do that for you.

And most importantly, If you are going to build a website in wordpress, you should check out the wordpress basics first.